# Debug: mounting /dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot failed: No such file or directory

Tags: raspbian, boot, sd-card, boot-issues, mount

I'm attempting to debug the below error I get during boot of [`raspbian-ua-netinst`](https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst) on a Pi 3 Model B v1.2:

```
Copying boot files... mounting /dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot failed: No such file or directory

Oh noes, something went wrong!
mount: mounting /dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot failed: No such file or directory`
unmount: can't unmount /boot: Invalid argument
```

I'm then given an option to activate a console;

```
Busybox v1.22.1 (Raspbian 1:1.22.0-9+deb8u1) built in shell (ash)
```

the /boot directory contains one empty file:

`raspbian-ua-netinst-197000101T000002.log`

the /dev directory contains a file `mmcblk0` but *not* `mmcblk0p1`

Looking at the source code it appears that the [`fail()`](https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst/blob/e3bc3ab8a671c9979b1f12c4480fd59695d21227/scripts/etc/init.d/rcS#L34) function in `init.d/rcS` is entered:

```
fail()
{
    echo
    echo "Oh noes, something went wrong!"
    echo "You have 10 seconds to hit ENTER to get a shell..."

    # copy logfile to /boot/ partition to preserve it.
    # test whether the sd card is still mounted on /boot and if not, mount it.
    if [ ! -f /boot/bootcode.bin ] ; then
        mount $bootpartition /boot
        fail_boot_mounted=true
    fi
    cp $LOGFILE /boot/raspbian-ua-netinst-`date +%Y%m%dT%H%M%S`.log
    sync

    # if we mounted /boot in the fail command, unmount it.
    if [ "$fail_boot_mounted" = true ] ; then
        umount /boot
    fi

    read -t 10 || reboot && exit
    sh
}
```

The is bootpartition is set to `/dev/mmcblk0p1` (the file referenced in the error) in [the preceding lines](https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst/blob/e3bc3ab8a671c9979b1f12c4480fd59695d21227/scripts/etc/init.d/rcS#L28):

```
# these shouldn't really be changed unless auto-detection fails
bootdev=/dev/mmcblk0
bootpartition=/dev/mmcblk0p1
rootdev=/dev/mmcblk0
rootpartition=
```

**What is going on here?**

**What steps should I take to debug this problem?**

*Note. [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118090/mounting-mmcblk0p1-failed-with-invalid-argument) seems to be addressing a similar problem.*

EDIT:

It is a similar issue to the one reported [here](https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst/issues/41).

This implies that it is a problem (no specific details) with the SD card resulting in an auto-detection failure.

EDIT 2:

A photo of the monitor output:

[image]

EDIT 3:

running `fdisk /dev/mmcblk0` and selecting `p` "print the partition table" gives:

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 62.5GB, 62537072640 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 1908480 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 64 * 512 = 32768 bytes

    Device Boot    Start    End    Blocks    Id System
```

Selecting `v` "verify the partion table" gives:

```
122142719 unallocated sectors
```

This is all bar 1 of the sectors; I take this to mean that there are no recognised partitions on the disk.